# How to center a font awesome icon over an image in bootstrap 3?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

I am trying to center a `font-awesome` icon over an image in `bootstrap 3`.

Here is the image code contained in a div:

```
<div id="quickVideo">
    <a data-fancybox href="https://player.vimeo.com/video/153113362?autoplay=1&color=54b3e4" class="adminDemoVideo">
        <img src="~/Images/..." class="img-responsive">
    </a>
</div>
```

I could do that using `::before` on div element but the problem here is that it is not responsive by default.

```
.adminDemoVideo::before {
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    content: '\f04b';
    margin-top: 1.35em;
    margin-left: 2.8em;
    color: white;
    z-index: 1000;
    font-size: 50px !important;
    position: absolute;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
    padding-top: 3px;
    padding-left: 25px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    background-color: rgba(23, 35, 34, 0.75);
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}
```

Here is how it looks like in desktop display size:

[image: Desktop View]

When I turn it into mobile or tablet view size it just get distorted due to margin etc just like below:

[image: Mobile or tablet view]

Is there any way how to fix it without knowing the screen size ? 
It does not matter for me if the solution is in `css` or `javascript` or `jquery`.

Hope this is not duplicate but did not find any proper solution here...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: how about using percentages in margin and padding ?

Comment: have you tried playing with the `top` and `left` properties? something like `top: calc(50% - width)` and `left: calc(50% - width)` where width would be the width of your icon?

Comment: I tried that with `calc` function too. I managed to fix it for a specific display size but when it turned to desktop mode again it became distorted. I tried something like that `left: calc(50% - 10em);` but did not fix the problem for all sizes because when the bootstrap resizes it ruins everything :(

Comment: `calc()` is a little inflexible in this case. `translate()` would be a better option. Set it once and forget it. The centered element can be any width/height and still center without having to redeclared `calc()` values for various meida queries or updating it.

Comment: Yeap this was the right answer, thanks a lot @hungerstar :) you saved me a lot of work. Cheers

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a common overlay question. The typical answer is use absolute positioning with translate inside a relative positioned parent.

- Make sure the parent has `position: relative;` so the absolute positioned overlay element doesn't end up somewhere where you don't want it. We're containing the overlay by doing this.
- Apply `position: absolute;` to the overlay element. Apply `50%` to `left` and `top`. This gets the top left corner of the overlay element to the center of the parent.
- Use `transform: translate( -50%, -50% );` to move the overlay up and to the left 50% of it's width and height. Now the center of the overlay is at the center of the parent.

```css
@import url( 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css' );
@import url( 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css' );

.adminDemoVideo {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.adminDemoVideo::before {
    content: '\f04b';
    z-index: 5;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate( -50%, -50% );
    padding: 3px 15px 3px 25px;
    color: white;
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    font-size: 50px !important;
    background-color: rgba(23, 35, 34, 0.75);
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}
```

```html
<a href="https://player.vimeo.com/video/153113362?autoplay=1&color=54b3e4" class="adminDemoVideo">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x800/fc0" class="img-responsive">
</a>
```

Note that the image that the anchor is wrapping will create a small amount of white space that is left for a descender in text so it will technically not be 100% vertically centered. If this is an issue you can remove this by setting the image to `display: block;`.

Comment: I think you got me in the right way, let me try and if it works in my case this will be the right marked answer :)